# Setting relative URL for javascript (websocket connecting to Spring MVC)

Tags: javascript, java, spring-mvc, websocket

I'm following this tutorial : https://www.baeldung.com/websockets-spring

I tested the app and it works perfectly when running on the embedded-tomcat server. However, when I try to deploy and run the same app on an external tomcat server it breaks, because instead of the URL being

```
localhost:8080/chat
```

it becomes

```
myhostIP:port/spring-boot-web-jsp/chat
```

So I modified the javascript file adding /spring-boot-web-jsp in front of the existing URLs. When I run the webapp the sockets connect successfully and send data. However now my Spring MVC Controller doesn't work.

My javascript :

```
        var stompClient = null;

        function setConnected(connected) {
            document.getElementById('connect').disabled = connected;
            document.getElementById('disconnect').disabled = !connected;
            document.getElementById('conversationDiv').style.visibility
              = connected ? 'visible' : 'hidden';
            document.getElementById('response').innerHTML = '';
        }

        function connect() {
            var socket = new SockJS('/spring-boot-web-jsp-1.0/chat');
            stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
            stompClient.connect({}, function(frame) {
                setConnected(true);
                console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
                stompClient.subscribe('/spring-boot-web-jsp-1.0/topic/messages', function(messageOutput) {
                    showMessageOutput(JSON.parse(messageOutput.body));
                });
            });
        }

        function disconnect() {
            if(stompClient != null) {
                stompClient.disconnect();
            }
            setConnected(false);
            console.log("Disconnected");
        }

        function sendMessage() {
            var from = document.getElementById('from').value;
            var text = document.getElementById('text').value;
            stompClient.send("/spring-boot-web-jsp-1.0/app/chat", {},
              JSON.stringify({'from':from, 'text':text}));
        }

        function showMessageOutput(messageOutput) {
            var response = document.getElementById('response');
            var p = document.createElement('p');
            p.style.wordWrap = 'break-word';
            p.appendChild(document.createTextNode(messageOutput.from + ": "
              + messageOutput.text + " (" + messageOutput.time + ")"));
            response.appendChild(p);
        }
```

My Controller :

```
@MessageMapping("/chat")
@SendTo("/topic/messages")
public OutputMessage send(Message message) throws Exception {
    String time = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").format(new Date());
    return new OutputMessage(message.getFrom(), message.getText(), time);
}
```

My message broker :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/chat");
        registry.addEndpoint("/chat").withSockJS();
    }
}
```

I've tried modifying the Controller to :

```
@MessageMapping("app/chat")
@SendTo("/topic/messages")
public OutputMessage send(Message message) throws Exception {
    String time = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").format(new Date());
    return new OutputMessage(message.getFrom(), message.getText(), time);
}

@MessageMapping("spring-boot-web-jsp-1.0/app/chat")
@SendTo("spring-boot-web-jsp-1.0/topic/messages")
public OutputMessage send(Message message) throws Exception {
    String time = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").format(new Date());
    return new OutputMessage(message.getFrom(), message.getText(), time);
}
```

and a bunch of other variations but none of them work. 
How can I modify the Controller and javascript file to work when testing through external Apache Tomcat as well as embedded (setting a relative URL of some sort)? And how can I get this to work properly on the external Tomcat?

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove your tomcat/webapps/ROOT directory
2. Rename your final jar/war/ear file to ROOT.jar/war/ear
3. Deploy it on tomcat

Tomcat will deploy your app under root directory localhost:8080/chat

Comment: Is this the only solution?

Comment: it is the most common one

Comment: This doesn't really solve my issue though. I have multiple webapps deployed and might run into the same problem with another app. If it's not possible to have relative paths, do you see what is causing my webapp to break? IDK what other URL to set my Controller.

Comment: you said that your hostname becomes myhostIP:port/spring-boot-web-jsp/chat
why did you change it to spring-boot-web-jsp-1.0/app/chat
try spring-boot-web-jsp-1.0/chat or spring-boot-web-jsp/chat

Comment: this spring-boot-web-jsp is the name of your final war. You can change the name of it in your pom.xml

Comment: Ideally you want to set up the app so that can run any context path.